# strtotime issue

Tags: php

I have created a code like

```
<?=date('h:m A',strtotime('09:30:00'))?>
```

I am getting  an output like 09:12 AM. The actual result will be 09:30 AM.
Why getting a result like the above?

Comment: Please use `<?php` to start PHP always.

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie: Please do not suggest this. In modern PHP versions the `<?= ... ?>` syntax **ALWAYS** works even with short_tags=off. So it is actually the preferred way when using PHP for templating.

Comment: What Modern? @ThiefMaster

Comment: *"Since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available."*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick look at the documentation of the [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function shows the mistake in your code:

> `m` Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
>   `i` Minutes with leading zeros

So you need `i` for the minute. The whole format string would be `'h:i A'`

However, it would be much better if you didn't use the `date` function but [`strftime`](http://php.net/strftime) which uses standardized format variables:

```
<?=strftime('%I:%M %p', strtotime('09:30:00'))?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for showing my mistake. I didn't notice that letter while bugging.